# Is there any way to route input/output from TinyScheme?

Tags: scheme, io

I'm using TinyScheme, and currently trying to route it's console input/output into my functions without on-disk file.
I'm using Cocoa Touch, and final goal is making remote interactive console.

I thinks some steps required, but I cannot how to implemented each steps. Especially, the how to using FILE structure.

Any recommendations & advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some details for remotely debugging Gambit Scheme on the iPhone; I know it's not TinyScheme, but you might get some ideas from it: http://jlongster.com/blog/2009/07/05/remotely-debugging-iphone-scheme/

Comment: Thanks. I just switched to Gambit.